# How to use recursive methods to check strings?

Tags: java, recursion

I have been tasked with using a recursive method to count the instances of the work "chicken" in a string, delete any instances in the string and check again, ending with an output of the amount of "chicken" removed. I had an easier time using a nested loop instead of a recursive and here is my code.

```
package recursive_labs;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChickenAnhilator {
public static String Test1;
public static int Checker(String Test1) {
String chicken = "chicken";
int i = 0;

int c = 0;
int z = 0;
if (Test1.length()<7){
    return z;
}
    for(i=0;i<Test1.length();i++) {
        if (true==(chicken==Test1.substring(i, i+6))){
            c++;
            Test1.replace("chicken","");
            i=0;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

//chicken
public static void main(String [] args) {
Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your string");
Test1 = Keyboard.next();
System.out.print(Checker(Test1));
}
}
```

After running this and inputting the string "chicken" I get these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at recursive_labs.ChickenAnhilator.Checker(ChickenAnhilator.java:15)
at recursive_labs.ChickenAnhilator.main(ChickenAnhilator.java:29)
```

I'm using eclipse and was wondering how to fix this error and if I could achieve this task without using a recursive method. Thanks!

Comment: This `chicken==Test1.substring(i, i+6)` will almost always be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked if there were a way to achieve this without using recurison. 
 This task is very easy using `String#replace`:

```
static final String CHICKEN = "chicken";
String input = "I like eating chicken and only a chicken would not eat it.";
int length = input.length();
input = input.replace(CHICKEN, "");
int numOccurrences = (length - input.length()) / CHICKEN.length();
```

### Demo

The only trick here which might merit explanation is how the number of occurrences is being calculated.  We may compare the lengths of the input string before and after replacement, and then divide that difference by the length of `chicken`.

**Edit:** You have pointed out an edge case where by deleting `chicken` actually leaves modified input with more occurrences of chicken.  In this case, you may iterate in a loop, replacing until the size of the input does not change:

```
static final String CHICKEN = "chicken";
String input = "I like eating chichickencken and only a chicken would not eat it.";
int numOccurrences = 0;
while (input.length() > 0) {
    int currLength = input.length();
    input = input.replace(CHICKEN, "");
    if (input.length() == currLength) break;
    numOccurrences += (currLength - input.length()) / CHICKEN.length();
}
```

### Demo

Comment: +1, but you may as well also use `replace()` rather than `replaceAll()`, as you're not using a regex. (I refuse to bow to the +1 ban...)

Comment: This seems much simpler than my code but after attempting it with one of the test inputs, "chichickencken", which should count 2 after deleting the middle "chicken" and counting the remaining one, it only output 1, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @BigNoseJones I will counter this by saying that the original string only had one `chicken`.  What you are describing is an edge case, not likely to happen.  If you do need to worry about this, then you may use a loop to iterate until the size of the input does not get any smaller.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Awesome, Thanks a ton, this is a lot simpler than my previous code and it actually works!

Comment: @BigNoseJones You may mark this answer correct, but also consider the other answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion has two cases: one terminal case, and one self-invocation case.

So, in pseudocode, a recursive algorithm would look like

```
int countChicken(String input) {
   if no "chicken" in input { return 0; }  // The terminal step.
   // chicken is here.
   int position_after = (end of position of "chicken" in string) + 1;
   String rest_of_string = input.substringAfter(position_after);
   return 1 + countChicken(rest_of_string); // The recursive step.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...just for the fun of counting chicken, my version looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class ChickenCounter {

    private static final String CHICKEN = "chicken";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ChickenCounter e = new ChickenCounter();
        Arrays.stream(new String[] {
                "chicken",
                "chicken chicken",
                "cchickenhicken",
                "I like eating chicken and only a chicken would not eat it."
        }).forEach(s -> System.out.println("'" + s + "' has " + e.count(s) + " chicken"));
    }

    private int count(String string) {
        if (!string.contains(CHICKEN)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + count(string.replaceFirst(CHICKEN, ""));
    }
}
```